# My sourdough starter has turned yellow is it still good?

Tags: bread, sourdough, starter

I have two sourdough starters going one I keep in the frig. the other on the counter. The one on the counter has all of a sudden turned yellow. It was fine yesterday and when I went to feed it today it had a crusty film on top and it is a pale yellow. Is it still good?

Neither one of my starters has hooch is that normal?  They have been going for about 3 to 4 weeks. They also are not very sour smelling. Will this just mean the bread wont be very sour? I got the start from a friend I used it and the bread was great. I saved some to do the two starters I have.
Thank you for any help

Comment: Pictures, please!

Comment: Are you keeping these in sealed containers?

Comment: Did you use the same water in each batch?

Comment: This might be related, based on the "crusty film" : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/65198/67

Comment: This really is two questions; one about whether yellow sourdough is still good; and a second about controlling the sourness of your sourdough. Checkout http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27852/how-can-you-change-the-environmental-factors-to-change-the-proportions-of-sourdo/27871#27871 for an answer related to controlling the sourness.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. I am going to get my daughter to show me how to post pictures. I'm kind of old school. Computers are not my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your starter has dried. Keep the starter in a cool place (fridge is too cold). Feed it every few days with flour and some water. Before adding the flour and water, discard maybe even half of the starter (best option is to bake every few days). Otherwise you'll end up with several pounds of starter... As with all food, use your senses. If it tastes and smells OK (for sourdough starter...), it's OK. 
So, to save your yellow starter, add a little moisture and fresh flour and see what happens. It takes a few days for the right growth and bubbles to appear.

Comment: The fridge is fine, if it is kept at proper temperature.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side make a new starter.Quick and easy with 1 cup flour, 1 cup milk kefir. Mix thourougly, let stay in room temperature for 2 to 3 days till it's bubbly. 
I always use the whole amount of starter -sometimes 500g- in my bread. Don't forget to keep some aside for the next bread. Kept in the fridge you only need to feed it every 7 to 10 days. Before the next baking feed your starter every 12 hours till it's bubbly.